# attempt to compress inside of (simple) function into more efficient code

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple function that adds and removes classes for elements (buttons).

```
function mainBut (){

  ba.classList.add("act2");
  ba.classList.remove("hov")

  bh1.classList.add("hov");
  bh1.classList.remove("act2");
  bh2.classList.add("hov");
  bh2.classList.remove("act2");

  da.classList.remove("none")
  dh1.classList.add("none")
  dh2.classList.add("none")
}
```

But as the number of elements grows, i see that the code could be better organized. Because we could:

remove: `.act2` for (`bh1` and `bh2`) | add: `.hov` for (`bh1` and `bh2`) | add: `.none` for (`dh1` and `dh2`).

I'm wondering, if it could be done using `for` loop? Or maybe there is a better way...

Comment: What's flow here, is it static, or the flows will vary?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What is the big picture?  You need to explain the context of what you want to do.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin write more compressed code. I have an Idea for a cleaner code, don`t know how to do it though. Functionality stays the same, just an attempt for cleaner and more efficient way of writing same thing.

Comment: @bartc could you please share your markup as well or better make a working snoippet?

Comment: @bartc We can't help without context. What is the range of possibilities.

Comment: guys i just see that instead of writing for every element: add this class, remove this class i could write it in more efficient way, couse some classess can be removed for two elements at once. just dont know how to put it in code

Comment: @bartc we do not know your markup structure. We do not know how manipulation is to happen. If you could just add markup, it would be easier for all of us to suggest

Comment: @bartc show a HTML example of the elements

Comment: guys but it is irrelevant for this question. my direct question is : how to add/remove a class, for two or more elements using js

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional programming to simplify it. Break-in small function and reuse.

```
const add = cls => elm => elm.classList.add(cls);
const remove = cls => elm => elm.classList.remove(cls);
const addAct2 = add("act2");
const addHov = add("hov");
const removeAct2 = remove("act2");
const removeHov = add("hov");
const addNone = add("none");
const removeNone = add("none");

function mainBut() {
  addAct2(ba);
  removeHov(ba);
  addHov(bh1);
  removeAct2(bh1);

  addHov(bh2);
  removeAct2(bh2);

  removeNone(da);
  addNone(dh1);
  addNone(dh2);
}
```

// MORE FUNTIONAL

```
const curry = (fn, arity = fn.length, ...args) =>
  arity <= args.length ? fn(...args) : curry.bind(null, fn, arity, ...args);

const apply = curry((fn, data =[]) => data.map(fn))

function mainBut() {
  apply(removeHov, apply(addAct2, [ba]))
  apply(removeAct2, apply(addHov, [bh1, bh2]))
  apply(removeNone, [da])
  apply(addNone, [da, dh1, dh2])
}
```